# How to make a torch (iPhone) with colored light in swift?

Tags: iphone, swift

I have tried to read AVFoundation documentation and I can't find anything about colors. Is it possible to change the color to red, green or blue? I think I have seen colored torch apps.

Would it be very hard to write your own code that controlled color hue or lumen of the flashlight?

Comment: I don’t think this is possible. Can you link to an app that does this?

Comment: I have not downloaded and tried this app, but it looks like you can choose different colors. http://appsfromouterspace.com/flashlight/

Comment: I think the different colors to choose from are only for the screen. The LED itself is only white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are apps that get around this by [display a brightly colored screen](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/colorlight/id354867719), the [flash on the iPhone is has a single LED element](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-make-the-flash-on-my-iPhone-6-shine-different-colors-Is-there-an-accessory-or-app-to-make-this-possible).

You do, via `AVCaptureDevice`, have the ability to change the intensity of torches on some models.  Take a look at the [`torchLevel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624605-torchlevel) property.

You could always [try an easy hardware hack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrjXcf--m6g).

Comment: LOL (the hardware hack) :-) 
So the app I linked to displays a colored screen? I was hoping there was a way to add background color as a property like device.torch.backgroudColor or something like that.

Comment: I'd suggest filing it as a feature request via http://bugreporter.apple.com -- the more people who ask for it, the more likely Apple will consider it.